# Scriptaculous Droppables onDrop callback, How to reference each element?

Tags: javascript, scriptaculous, droppable

Documentation can be found [here](http://github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/wikis/droppables)

It says in the example:

**onDrop:
Called whenever a Draggable is released over the Droppable and the Droppable is accepts it. The callback gets three parameters: the Draggable element, the Droppable element and the Event. You can extract additional information about the drop – like if the Ctrl or Shift keys were pressed – from the Event object.**

Then it gives some code

Droppables.add('shopping_cart', {
  accept: 'products',
  onDrop: function(element) {
    $('shopping_cart_text').update('Dropped the ' + element.alt + ' on me.');
  }
});

It uses the ambiguous word 'element' in the code.  **My question is, does anyone have a good example on how to reference the draggable element and the droppable element in this callback javascript function?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by the example further down the page, the callback function can take as many of the parameters as you need:

```
onDrop: function() { $('droppable_demo').highlight(); }
```

In this case, they have used none of the callback parameters.  To this end, presumably to access all three as mentioned in the paragraph you quoted, you can define:

```
onDrop: function(dragged, dropped, event) {  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this example to the documentation...

```
 Droppables.add('shopping_cart', {
  accept: 'products',
  onDrop: function(dragged, dropped, event) {
    alert('Dragged: ' + dragged.id);
    alert('Dropped onto: ' + dropped.id);
    alert('Held ctrl key: ' + event.ctrlKey);
  }
});
```